# How do I get my div to scale with conent?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I am trying to make something like a timeline and I have multiple `divs` with text in it.

I want it to be responsive, so on desktop they are low and wide, but on mobile they are thin and long. But not every `div` will have the same amount of text in it so they are not all going to be the same height.

How do I get the `divs` to scale in height with the content. In `width` I got it with percent width, but I don't see how that would work on height.

I am also quite novice in coding so I'd appreciate it there is a HTML/CSS solution, so no JS. But if it's relatively simple code, I am willing to give it a try.

```html
<style>
  .text {
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #D3D8E6;
  }

  .text p {
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    color: #002B5C;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    font-family: arial;
  }

  .text h1 {
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    color: #002B5C;
    font-family: arial;
  }

  .container-tekst-links {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    max-height: 750px;
  }

  .img {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-radius: 0px 25px 25px 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 190px;
    height: 130px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>2004</h1><br />
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

  </div>
  <img class="img" src="https://www.cranepartssupply.com/media/wysiwyg/WerkplaatsBuitenzicht_Web.jpg" />
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jp_isthataname/bk6atc2o/12/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple answer here, just change `height` to `auto` on `.text`. You don't need to specify it if it's forever changing. Working snippet below:

```html
<style>
  .text {
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #D3D8E6;
  }

  .text p {
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    color: #002B5C;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    font-family: arial;
  }

  .text h1 {
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin-bottom: -25px;
    color: #002B5C;
    font-family: arial;
  }

  .container-tekst-links {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    max-height: 750px;
  }

  .img {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-radius: 0px 25px 25px 0px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 190px;
    height: 130px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <h1>2004</h1><br />
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

  </div>
  <img class="img" src="https://www.cranepartssupply.com/media/wysiwyg/WerkplaatsBuitenzicht_Web.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the height to 'auto'. That is the only thing you need.

```
.text {
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #D3D8E6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it using the **Bootstrap** framework
Open this snippet in full-page and try resizing your browser, this work in both desktop and in mobile devices

```css
.text {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 5px solid #D3D8E6;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text col-12 col-xl-8 my-auto">
      <h1>2004</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-xl-4">
      <img class="img" src="https://www.cranepartssupply.com/media/wysiwyg/WerkplaatsBuitenzicht_Web.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Telling someone to install a whole CSS framework for something that can done with one line of code is overkill. Although this is technically a valid answer, it's a poor one. We should always look for the easiest way for the OP to solve a problem.